# Creating custom service on Linux to communicate with modem over serial UART

Tags: c, linux, service, serial-port, modem

I have written a program in C to communicate with a 3G modem connected to my raspberry pi over serial uart. After it's open, I do not break the connection unless the program crashes. It runs fine when I run it myself, but when I create a service to run it, it fails right after it starts.

My main question, is this an issue with my program, or is this an issue with how I configured my linux service to run? And what is the best practices to fix this.

my service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Firmware for sensor IOT module
Documentation=m.thompson.239@gmail.com
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/hdd/firmware
StandardOutput=syslog
RestartSec=30
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=firmware.service
```

When I check the status of the service

```
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/firmware.service; enabled; vendor preset:
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: signal) since Thu 2018-07-12 14:44
  Process: 539 ExecStart=/hdd/firmware (code=killed, signal=SEGV)
 Main PID: 539 (code=killed, signal=SEGV)

Jul 12 14:44:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: firmware.service: Failed with result 'si
lines 1-7/7 (END)...skipping...
● firmware.service - Firmware for sensor IOT module
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/firmware.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: signal) since Thu 2018-07-12 14:44:34 UTC; 28s ago
  Process: 539 ExecStart=/hdd/firmware (code=killed, signal=SEGV)
 Main PID: 539 (code=killed, signal=SEGV)

Jul 12 14:44:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: firmware.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

These are my setting when I open the serial port.

```
    int set_interface_attribs(int fd, int speed)
{
  struct termios tty;

  if (tcgetattr(fd, &tty) < 0) {
    printf("Error from tcgetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
  }

  cfsetospeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);
  cfsetispeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);

  tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);    /* ignore modem controls */
  tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
  tty.c_cflag |= CS8;         /* 8-bit characters */
  tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;     /* no parity bit */
  tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;     /* only need 1 stop bit */
  tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;    /* no hardware flowcontrol */

  /* setup for non-canonical mode */
  tty.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
  tty.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
  tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

  /* fetch bytes as they become available */
  tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
  tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;

  if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
    printf("Error from tcsetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the posted code has anything to do with the failure?

Comment: I read a similar post where linux was reading a signal between the serial port and service as an error and terminating the process.

Comment: I found the answer though, I'm an idiot. I just needed to add the "WorkingDirectory=" line to my .service file. I had a file it couldn't read because it was looking in the wrong directory.